# How to transform a json structure with jq

Tags: json, structure, jq, transform

How can I transform (using `jq`) the following *json* structure from this:

```
{
  "_internal_messages": {
    "error": [
      {
        "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 1,
        "origin": "A",
        "text": "This is an error message"
      },
      {
        "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 5,
        "origin": "A",
        "text": "This is a second error message"
      }
    ],
    "info": [
      {
        "date": "16:12:29 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 0,
        "origin": "A",
        "text": "This is an info message"
      },
      {
        "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 4,
        "origin": "C",
        "text": "This is a second info message"
      }
    ],
    "success": [
      {
        "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 2,
        "origin": "B",
        "text": "This is a success message"
      },
      {
        "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 3,
        "origin": "B",
        "text": "This is a second success message"
      },
      {
        "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
        "id": 6,
        "origin": "C",
        "text": "This is a third success message"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To this:

```
{"_internal_messages":[
  {
    "type":"info",
    "date": "16:12:29 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 0,
    "origin": "A",
    "text": "This is an info message"
  },{
    "type":"error",
    "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 1,
    "origin": "A",
    "text": "This is an error message"
  },{
    "type":"success",
    "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 2,
    "origin": "B",
    "text": "This is a success message"
  },{
    "type":"success",
    "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 3,
    "origin": "B",
    "text": "This is a second success message"
  },{
    "type":"info",
    "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 4,
    "origin": "C",
    "text": "This is a second info message"
  },{
    "type":"error",
    "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 5,
    "origin": "A",
    "text": "This is a second error message"
  },{
    "type":"success",
    "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
    "id": 6,
    "origin": "C",
    "text": "This is a third success message"
  }
]}
```

I checked the *jq Manual* and some other previous answered questions at SO, but I was not able to crack this one out... I´m thinking in combining `jq` with `bash` to do it, but I´m sure there must be a better way using just `jq` but my skills are not there yet. Can someone help me out, please? Thanks!

In the original structure the messages are stored in 3 arrays: `error`, `info` and `success`. Each time a message is added to those arrays, it receives a consecutive/incremental `id`. What I want is to take all those messages out from the three arrays, put them in one array while adding an extra attribute to know where each message came from (`error`, `info` or `success`) and finally order them in asc order by their id. The tricky part is knowing which one is an `error`, `info` or a `success` once you put them all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why one of the items is missing in your desired output, but apart from that it's flattening the object with mapping the key to another field:

```bash
jq '._internal_messages |= (to_entries | map({type: .key} + .value[]))'
```

```json
{
  "_internal_messages": [
    {
      "type": "error",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 1,
      "origin": "A",
      "text": "This is an error message"
    },
    {
      "type": "error",
      "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 5,
      "origin": "A",
      "text": "This is a second error message"
    },
    {
      "type": "info",
      "date": "16:12:29 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 0,
      "origin": "A",
      "text": "This is an info message"
    },
    {
      "type": "info",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 4,
      "origin": "C",
      "text": "This is a second info message"
    },
    {
      "type": "success",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 2,
      "origin": "B",
      "text": "This is a success message"
    },
    {
      "type": "success",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 3,
      "origin": "B",
      "text": "This is a second success message"
    },
    {
      "type": "success",
      "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 6,
      "origin": "C",
      "text": "This is a third success message"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

If you want the items to be sorted by `.id`, append a `sort_by`:

```bash
jq '._internal_messages |= (to_entries | map({type: .key} + .value[]) | sort_by(.id))'
```

```json
{
  "_internal_messages": [
    {
      "type": "info",
      "date": "16:12:29 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 0,
      "origin": "A",
      "text": "This is an info message"
    },
    {
      "type": "error",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 1,
      "origin": "A",
      "text": "This is an error message"
    },
    {
      "type": "success",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 2,
      "origin": "B",
      "text": "This is a success message"
    },
    {
      "type": "success",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 3,
      "origin": "B",
      "text": "This is a second success message"
    },
    {
      "type": "info",
      "date": "16:12:30 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 4,
      "origin": "C",
      "text": "This is a second info message"
    },
    {
      "type": "error",
      "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 5,
      "origin": "A",
      "text": "This is a second error message"
    },
    {
      "type": "success",
      "date": "16:12:31 - 07/02/2023",
      "id": 6,
      "origin": "C",
      "text": "This is a third success message"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the item id=0 in the code. All items should be present in the desired output. I edited my question.